# Sending an intent from onActivityDestroyed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a self-update service which extends `NullSafeJobIntentService` and listens to trigger_update intents and marked as `android:exported="false"` in manifest.

I have a single main activity. I am sending a `trigger_update` intent In [onDestroyed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks#onActivityDestroyed(android.app.Activity)) method.

Is this reliable? I am always seeing the app gets updated as the intent reaches the service before the process is killed (The process importance becomes 230: [IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo#IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE))

1. Is this a reliable way to make sure the app is updated (in prod) only when user closes the app and not minimises it?
2. Any resources which I can use to prove this is reliable
3. Any alternatives to achieve this?
4. Even if the intent gets delayed and process gets killed, would android not restart the application for the intent?

Note that my app is system app so update does not need user permission